# Unable to convert ASCII html code to String

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a String which has html ASCII code in it such as follows:

```
"Hello, world! &#135; end"
```

After conversion, I am looking to achieve the following:

```
"Hello, world! ‡ end"
```

But I end up with:

```
Hello, world!  end
```

Why?

ASCII Table just for reference if needed.

https://www.ascii-code.com/

Tried both following methods resulting in same outcome.

Attempt 1

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
String str = "Hello, world! &#135; end";
String res = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(str); // same for unescapeHtml3
System.out.println(res); // "Hello, world!  end"
```

Attempt 2

```
String getUpdatedStr() {
    String str = "Hello, world! &#135; end";
    String regex = "&#(\\d+);";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int asciiValue = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        char asciiChar = (char) asciiValue;
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Character.toString(asciiChar));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString(); // "Hello, world!  end" 
}
```

Comment: I think `&#135;` only works when ISO-8859-1 is used. Since we live in a UTF world, try `&#8225;` instead.

Comment: ... thus, you are not looking for ASCII but UTF (UTF8 typically). Please rephrase your question. Otherwise, in ASCII what you want is impossible.

Comment: @f1sh Thanks, makes sense. &#8225; worked and that would fit for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

The translation you are trying to perform here would require a non-standard interpretation of HTML character references.

According to the HTML 5 specification (see [HTML 5 - 8.1.4 Character references](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/syntax.html#character-references)) the numeric codes in a decimal or hexadecimal character reference are Unicode codepoints.  The Unicode codepoint you using there is U+0087 which is a control code (ESA or End of Selected Area).  It is not a printing character.

So ... in fact ... your first attempt is most likely giving you the **correct** translation of `&#135;`.  It is there ... but you can't see anything when you print it on a normal console.

As others have noted, the HTML character reference for the ‡ character is actually `&#8225`.

---

Note that the meaning of an HTML character reference does not depend on the character encoding used in the HTML document representation; e.g. per the HTTP `Content-type` header or the document's `<meta>` tag.  The HTML 5 spec says that it is Unicode, and that's it.